# completion handler always returns an empty array except when called from code that populate array

Tags: swift, uikit, urlsession

Im having some difficulties with completition handler. I don't want to use new async/await feature untill learning the old way.

This is my @escaping fetch() func:

```
  func fetch(completion: @escaping (Result<[CountriesFinal], CountryError>) -> Void) {
let urlString = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fdsfdghjfvghdfhf.json"

let url = URL(string: urlString)!

   let _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
       guard let jsonData = data else {
           completion(.failure(.noDataAvailable))
           return
       }
       do {
           let decoder = JSONDecoder()
           let countriesResponse = try decoder.decode(Country.self, from: jsonData)
           let countryDetails = countriesResponse.countries
           completion(.success(countryDetails))

       } catch {
           completion(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
       }
   }.resume()
}
```

I've learned that fetch() should be called like this inside viewDidLoad():

```
  // var countriess = [CountriesFinal]() // outside of viewDidLoad

  fetch { result in
          switch result {
          case let .failure(error):
              print(error)
          case let .success(holidays):
              self.countriess = holidays
              print(self.countriess[0].name) // WORKS ✔️
              
          }
    }
    // If written here or in any other func:
    print(self.countriess[0].name) // Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

Comment: `fetch` is an async method. You are printing the result before it completes the request. Inside the closure is where your code should be placed. If you need to do anything after the request is completed call another method from there

Comment: Do I need to change or implement something that is not already in my code?@LeoDabus

Comment: As I said create another method and call it from where it "works". Btw you should always check if your collection indices contains the desired index before subscripting your array. `if self.countriess.indices.contains(index) {`. This will avoid crashing your App.

Comment: Haven't saw your edited comment...I thought that it shouldn't be done and that there is another way, thank you

Comment: You can't assume that your back end will never return an empty array. If it is always returning just a single element you can get its first element `if let country = self.countriess.first {` this way you don't need to check if it contains the zero index.

Comment: `print(self.countriess[0].name) // WORKS ✔️` => `print("Inside fetch closure: \(self.countriess[0].name)") // WORKS ✔️` and `print(self.countriess[0].name) // Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` => `print("Outside fetch closure: \(self.countriess[0].name)") // Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`, this way you might see from which one and especially when the prints occurs, when your array is populated, and the order might not be the one you think of. I think that's the best way to understand/see the async system. So it's normal to get that error because your array is still empty.

Comment: Always add an "info" on your `print()`, it will let you know from where they are called.